# printing from apache/php

Tags: php, apache, printing

i have a java based desktop app that i am hoping to rewrite as a php web app.

In the desktop application there is a publish button, that prints multiple copies of the race results to several printers at once, eg results tent, admin, announcers, etc

Server is a windows machine running xampp
All printers are network printers and are available directly from server

My initial thoughts are to generate a pdf file and print that via shell exec call, but i am not sure how to control which printer it goes too, and how many copies will come out.

Has anyone tried doing this before, i want to make sure it is all possible before i start

Comment: If you're running a linux call, are you sure this isn't a linux question?

Comment: Its definitely possible, we're printing from an ASP.net application (intranet) to network printers - generally the biggest thing issue is rights. As for the actual printing - like you said a shell exec, or perhaps a simple COM call (since its a windows server)

Comment: no linux call, its a windows server as noted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion its posible like this code

```
require('./fpdf.php');

$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output('c:\test1.pdf');
shell_exec("'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 6.0\Reader\acrord32.exe' /t c:\test1.pdf \\myserver\myprinter");
?>
```

Comment: do you know if it is possible to adjust the number of copies via the cmdline, it is quite common for us to print multiple copies

Comment: you must create the batch file for this resone and then run the batch file for the number of copy maybe you can do this in the loop

Comment: i think i am going to go for a solution like this, but i am looking at using this app http://www.coolutils.com/TotalPDFPrinter instead of acrobat reader to print as it gives more cmdline options to control the printing. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the printer extension in windows like this

at first do this

`Windows users must enable php_printer.dll inside of php.ini`

then

```
$handle = printer_open();
printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");
printer_start_page($handle);

printer_end_page($handle);
printer_end_doc($handle);
printer_close($handle);
?>
```